# Is this Python function able to be be converted to Javascript?

Tags: javascript, python, encryption

I am working with ciphers; encrypting and decrypting and I'm currently working with the [Polybius Cipher](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/polybius-square-cipher/) with the modern Latin alphabet. For example, the letters 'a' is the 2-digit code, '11' and 'abc' is '11 12 13'.

I have found a solution in Python:

```
# Python Program to implement polybius cipher 
  
# function to display polybius cipher text 
def polybiusCipher(s): 
  
        # convert each character to its encrypted code 
        for char in s: 
              
                # finding row of the table 
                row = int((ord(char) - ord('a')) / 5) + 1
          
                # finding column of the table  
                col = ((ord(char) - ord('a')) % 5) + 1
  
                # if character is 'k' 
                if char == 'k': 
                        row = row - 1
                        col = 5 - col + 1
                          
                # if character is greater than 'j' 
                elif ord(char) >= ord('j'): 
                        if col == 1 : 
                            col = 6
                            row = row - 1
                              
                        col = col - 1
                          
                print(row, col, end ='', sep ='')
```

I am trying to convert it and keep getting `NaN` as I am misusing something, or multiple things. Here is what I have so far:

```
function polybius(input, encode = true) {
  for (let i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
    let letter = input[i];

    let row = letter.charCodeAt(0 - letter.charCodeAt(97)) / 5 + 1;

    let col = letter.charCodeAt(0 - (letter.charCodeAt(97) % 5)) + 1;

    if (letter.charCodeAt(0) === letter.charCodeAt(107)) {
      row = row - 1;
      col = 5 - col + 1;
    } else if (letter.charCodeAt(0) >= letter.charCodeAt(106)) {
      if (col === 1) {
        col = 6;
        row = row - 1;
      }
      col = col - 1;
    }
    return `${row}${col} `;
  }
}
```

Comment: [`.charCodeAt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charCodeAt#Parameters) requires an integer as an argument - 'a' won't produce the results you expect.

Comment: @iota - I've updated my comment to reflect that, but that is still the issue in this code.

Comment: I tried https://stevs.net/converter/ but it seems to be horrible

Comment: @RandyCasburn I change the argument for .charCodeAt() to have 0 as opposed to i. I also changed 'a', 'j' and 'k' to their respecive UNICODE numbers of 97, 106, and 107. I now get an actual number when I run the code. The letter a returns 20.498

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`let row = letter.charCodeAt(i - letter.charCodeAt('a')) / 5 + 1;` is not correct since the char code of the letter itself is `letter.charCodeAt(0)` and the char code of `'a'` is `'a'.charCodeAt(0)`. Moreover, you need to use `Math.floor` to round down.

Thus, it should be `let row = Math.floor((letter.charCodeAt(0) - 'a'.charCodeAt(0)) / 5) + 1;`.

There is a similar problem with the `col` initialization and it should be `let col = (letter.charCodeAt(0) - 'a'.charCodeAt(0)) % 5 + 1;`.

Next, to check if the letter is `k`, there is no need to compare char codes, you can directly use `letter === 'k'`. For the comparison to see if the letter is greater than or equal to `'j'`, a similar issue exists and you can directly use `>= 'j'`.

Finally, you return in the first iteration of the loop, so it will only run once. Instead, you can build a string to output or return at the end.

```
function polybius(input, encode = true) {
  let str = '';
  for (let i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
    let letter = input[i];

    let row = Math.floor((letter.charCodeAt(0) - 'a'.charCodeAt(0)) / 5) + 1;

    let col = (letter.charCodeAt(0) - 'a'.charCodeAt(0)) % 5 + 1;

    if (letter === 'k') {
      row = row - 1;
      col = 5 - col + 1;
    } else if (letter >= 'j') {
      if (col === 1) {
        col = 6;
        row = row - 1;
      }
      col = col - 1;
    }
   str += `${row}${col} `;
  }
  console.log(str);
}
```